# UK movie with disguised alien scientist trying to leave Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been searching for quite a while the name of an old UK sci fi film, that I once saw roughly around 1993-94.

To be brief I will only mention that after many escapes from government agents an incredulous woman scientific assistant is told by her protege that he is an alien on a reconnaissance mission to Earth. They take refuge in a public park; eventually he tells her that the noise they are about to hear and the spacecraft they see later, are there to try to establish contact with the Earth, and if he does not return to the ship he will die/disappear. The camera moves to the sky and when she turns back he is no longer there and the spacecraft leaves too, much to the dismay of the government agents who appear on the scene.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/101407) to see if anything there triggers any more details.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? You also stated you were being brief, if you have left anything out that you do remember I encourage you to edit it in, remember every detail, no matter how small, can help us identify this for you.

Comment: Do you mean that the alien is a protege of the assistant, or the other way around?  A scientific assistant sounds like a fairly junior position, and it seems odd for her to be directing someone even more junior.